# checking environment tire.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

This is my `config/initializers/tire.rb` file:

```
if Rails.env.production?
 Tire.configure do
  url "http://remoteserver.com:9200"
 end
end
```

If I try on my production server:

```
bundle exec rake environment tire:import CLASS=Object FORCE=true RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get error:

```
The original exception was: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)>
```

If I remove the `if` sentence is working fine.

**How can I to know rails environment on tire.rb file?**

Comment: what if you try RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake tire:import..  does the if work at that point

Comment: Thank you but how add this command to `tire.rb` file? This is a command for reindex with rake...

Comment: where do you run it from?   You can set the RAILS_ENV=production in the shell on the server so that all your commands  will run in production mode by default.  are you running this from cron? or something along those lines.

Comment: I'm running this command in capistrano. I have edited my question. I want use my localhost elastic search server in development and my remote elastic search server in production. Thank  you!

Comment: do you have the do at the end of if Rails.env.production?  as `if Rails.env.production? do `    That might help.  Your other option is just put the initialize in production.rb.  Your way should work though.

Comment: Your last response is the best :). If you want you can add this response for your karma. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Tire initialization code to `config/environments/production.rb`  as opposed to  checking for it in the tire.rb file (remove the tire.rb initializer when you move it)

Another thing I've done in the past is a YAML configuration file as talked about in http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised.  Then you can just link the settings you need in the same way you do database.yml.

Comment: This code is not working for me. The code that it's working for me is put the tire code inside production.rb. Please change this response for I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A Rails initializer (`config/initializers/tire.rb`) is normally a perfectly fine place for Rails configuration.

Check out the application [template](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/examples/rails-application-template.rb), or better, generate an example application with it and change it eg to:

```
Tire.configure do
  url 'http://localhost:9201'
end
```

You should see it applied correctly -- when you run `bundle exec rake environment tire:import:all`, you'll see `Skipping index creation, cannot connect to Elasticsearch`

Of course, when you want to configure Elasticsearch URL differently in development/production/etc, it's a good idea to put it into the environment configuration file. Another solution is to use the `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` environment variable, which is supported by Tire out of the box, and used on Heroku, Bonsai, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. +1 by this explanation detailed!